# Runtime error : Automation Error , The interface is unknown

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am getting runtime error "interface is unknown".

I have used the code.

Don't know why I am getting this error.

> Run-time error ‘-2147023179 (800706b5)”: Automation error The
> interface is unkown.

```
Sub copy_sheet_from_folder(ws_the_tool As Workbook)

    Dim source As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim wb_from As Workbook
    
    source = ws_the_tool.Path
    
    If InStr(1, source, "http") Then

        Dim IE As InternetExplorerMedium
        Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium
        IE.Visible = False
        IE.Navigate source
        Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        IE.Quit
        Set IE = Nothing
        
        Dim bIsSSL As Boolean
        bIsSSL = InStr(1, source, "https:") > 0
        
        source = Replace(Replace(source, "/", "\"), "%20", " ")
        source = Replace(Replace(source, "https:", vbNullString), "http:", vbNullString)
        source = Replace(source, Split(source, "\")(2), Split(source, "\")(2) & "@SSL\DavWWWRoot")
        
        If Not bIsSSL Then source = Replace(source, "@SSL\", vbNullString)
        
    End If
    
    source = source & "\measure_files\"
    strFile = Dir(source)
    
    Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=source & strFile
        strFile = Dir()
        Set wb_from = ActiveWorkbook
        Call copy_sheets(ws_the_tool, wb_from)
        wb_from.Close savechanges:=False
        
    Loop
    
    'Call copy_sheets(ws_the_tool)
    
End Sub
```

Please suggest why I am getting this error. I have searched this error message and can't find a solution that seems to work for me.

Comment: On what line does this error occur? (Single step through the code to find out)

Comment: You've tagged both vba6 & vba7 - are you actually using both? Otherwise please only tag the relevant technology.